# Convert string to date in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date

I'm trying to convert a `string` into a date format

My string looks like this

```
Dim MyString as String = "June 2011"
```

And I'm trying to convert it like this

```
Convert.ToDateTime(MyString).ToString("MM yyyy")
```

But it's giving me the error

> Syntax error converting datetime from
>   character string.

The desired output would be either `06/2011` or `01/06/2011`. The value of my string will only ever have the month and year in though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Prepend the day on the front of the string before converting it. You can use a format string to eliminate the day when outputting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A datetime object in .NET represents one single point in time. To create one from a Gregorian calendar date, you need all three parts (day, month, year), otherwise it can't represent one single point in time.

Since your business requirement is to assume that the day number is 1 if not provided, just insert that number into the string before parsing.

```
Dim myDate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime("1 " & MyString)
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, forgot to mention that string manipulations like that are of course culture-dependent. You don't mention what culture you are in. `"June 2011"` can imply either `en-GB` or `en-US`. Since inserting the day number at the start of the string is easier than trying to insert it between the month and year, I suggest you go for something like this.

```
Dim myDate1 As Date = Date.Parse("1 " & myString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces)
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert.ToDateTime() only takes the full date so try prepending 01 as the day first i.e.

Convert.ToDateTime("01 " + MyString)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Parse(MyString).ToString("MM yyyy")
```

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx): Convert.ToDateTime internally calls the DateTime.Parse method using the formatting information in a DateTimeFormatInfo object that is initialized for the current culture. So if this works for you, it must have something to do with the current culture, not with the fact that he uses Convert.ToDateTime as opposed to DateTime.Parse.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
    Dim provider As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    Dim MyString As String

    Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.Now 'test start

    'test all Month Year strings
    For x As Integer = 1 To 12
        MyString = d.ToString("MMMM yyyy") 'convert date to March 2011 then April 2011 then...
        Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "MMMM yyyy", provider)
        Debug.WriteLine(MyString & "   " & dt.ToString)
        d = d.AddMonths(1)
    Next
```

Comment: ParseExact - which allows me to define the formatting of the input string